# convert evt.data from websocket to jSON string or plain string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

Recently I played with websocket and it works great,

in the client side with onmessage(evt) function, I received a message from the server side,
the message is actually a JSON format like this:

```
{"Properties":{"name":"0a67d327-1f78-475e-b58a-d16706782223","publicname":"Page1"}}
```

then in the client side(html5 with javascript) I access the data using:

```
var page=evt.data;
```

then I access the JSON object

```
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML=page.Properties.name;
```

but it just won't work, I even use the eval function but it still doesn't work,
I did check the page by using alert(page);

I wonder if the evt.data is not a string data but a byte,
anyone have a solution for converting byte to string?
or any other solution that may have something to do with this evt.data

Answer (score 3):

WebSocket data is either string, Blob, or ArrayBuffer. In your case it is most likely a string so you need to parse it first:

```
var page = JSON.parse(evt.data);
console.log("Properties.name: " + page.Properties.name);
```

Comment: the parse didn't work, maybe browser issue, and I just found out that apparently the string that was sent from the server lack JSON format, like missing the brackets,so the eval wasn't able to convert